# Apply multiple quality checks on pandas dataframe across columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': [101,102,103,201,202],
                  'test_id':['A1:123,A25668','B1:TEST,B2456,B3#123','B3:456','B3:678,C1:345','C2:367,C3']})
```

Currently, I would like to validate whether selected columns in the dataframe meets the quality criteria

a) Columns should not contain duplicates

b) Column should not contain missing values

c) Column should contain only numeric/integer values. There should be no string/float values

So, I tried the below quality checks

```
q_1 = np.where(df['subject_id'].isna(),"No","Yes")
q_2 = np.where(df['subject_id'].duplicated(keep=False),"No","Yes")
q_3 = np.where(df['subject_id'].str.isdigit(),"Yes", "No") #but this throws error due int64.
q_4 = np.where(df['test_id'].isna(),"No","Yes")
q_5 = np.where(df['test_id'].duplicated(keep=False),"No","Yes")
q_6 = np.where(df['test_id'].str.isdigit(),"Yes", "No") #but this throws error due int64.
```

How to do this elegantly and efficiently across different columns in the dataframe? you can see that I am repeating same line of code multiple times for different columns

How do I verify whether the subject_id contains only integer and not string/float? I would like to check it row by row.

Comment: The goal is unclear in some ways. Do you need 6 variables with this information stored?

Comment: @HenryEcker, yes. correct..But do I have to write 6 lines of code for that? was trying to learn whether there is any pythonic way to do this efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can iterate over the column names in the given list, then for each column check the given conditions and create the corresponding flag columns

```
cols = ['subject_id', 'test_id']

for c in cols:
    df[c + '_missing'] = df[c].isna()
    df[c + '_duplicated'] = df[c].duplicated(keep=False)
    df[c + '_numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce') % 1 == 0
```

---

```
print(df)

   subject_id               test_id  subject_id_missing  subject_id_duplicated  subject_id_numeric  test_id_missing  test_id_duplicated  test_id_numeric
0         101         A1:123,A25668               False                  False                True            False               False             True
1         102  B1:TEST,B2456,B3#123               False                  False                True            False               False             True
2         103                B3:456               False                  False                True            False               False             True
3         201         B3:678,C1:345               False                  False                True            False               False             True
4         202             C2:367,C3               False                  False                True            False               False             True
```

Comment: @TheGreat Sure. Lets discuss here:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237694/ds5

Comment: Hi @Shubham - Will you be able to help me with this?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/556061/linear-regression-for-longitudinal-data

Comment: Hi @TheGreat Give me some time..I'll check that in a while.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Sharma for your help